# How to Set Java JDK Environment Variable for Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Can anybody tell me how to set environment variable for Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. 
I just upgrade my Mac to Mac OS X 10.8. When I run a script. It said that

"/Users/ruijiaoli/lejos_nxj/bin/nxj: line 64: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory"

I found that JDK in the directory within the path above. And it worked well in Mac OS X lion.
Is the JDK path changed in Mac OS X mountain Lion? The version of Java on my system is 1.6.

Answer (score 28):

This is what I have tried:

create the bash_profile:

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

add this to the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

execute the source command

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

echo JAVA_HOME:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 12):

I created a file ~/.bash_profile and added:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/sparkyspider/dev/javalibs/Grails/grails-2.1.1/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And all's working great for me...

Comment: Where did you placed the file?

Comment: ~ represents the user directory, so in other words /Users/user/.bash_profile

Comment: That method works only for the user's own environment. If you need such environment variables as a system-wide level, apparently you need to put corresponding setenv commands into a file /etc/launchd.conf.

Comment: Hi @Bogdan, "~" meaning user home directory. Example "/Users/ravi". So ".bash_profile" should be in "/Users/ravi/"

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following post very helpful -

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

It explains how to set the path for a single user or system wide (OS X Leopard+)