# What is the $ before shell command

Tags: java, macos, bash, shell

I am not used to shell commands and I'm trying to set up Apache Cordova on my Mac, I have difficulties to set up the PATH for the Java JDK. I'm trying to do like in the third answerer of this[question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089697/how-to-set-java-jdk-environment-variable-for-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion).
But whenever I search for setting up jdk's path, I see some lines of command with the $. I understand that what follows it is a command, but is the $ itself a command or some command to enters before like the 'sudo'. Or is it just a notation to tell it's a bash command ? 
I searched on google but didn't found anything, maybe I searched with the wrong keywords ? 
Anyway thanks for helping me.

Comment: *is it just a notation to tell it's a bash command?* Yes, it is.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: @EtanReisner that's for `$`s (technically `$(...)`) that are *inside* the command, not at the beginning.

Comment: @Jon What? Are you suggesting that `$(echo echo foo)` and `echo $(echo foo)` are somehow different uses of `$(...)`?

Comment: @EtanReisner No, I'm suggesting that something like `$ source ~/.bash_profile` (what the OP is referencing) is *very* different than `echo $(echo foo)` (what you are referencing).

Comment: lol, its just to show that it is the command line and not output

Comment: @Jon Ah! You assumed he meant lines 1, 3, and 4 in that answer (ignoring `$JAVA_HOME`). I assumed he meant line 2. You could very well be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much just there as a separator between the prompt and what you actually type. It's like the > in a Windows/DOS prompt. It indicates a normal user privileges. If the shell had superuser privileges, there would be a # instead of a $.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, it **is** the prompt, the right-hand end of it anyway

Answer (score 0):

> A $ prefixing a variable name indicates the value the variable holds.
>
> end-of-line. In a regular expression, a "$" addresses the end of a line of text.
>
> ${}      Parameter substitution.
>
> $' ... '     Quoted string expansion. This construct expands single or
> multiple escaped octal or hex values into ASCII or Unicode characters.
>
> $*, $@   positional parameters.
>
> $?  exit status variable. The $? variable holds the exit status of a command, a function, or of the script itself.
>
> $$  process ID variable. The $$ variable holds the process ID of the script in which it appears.