# WildFly not starting up in Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, maven, jboss, wildfly-10

Greeting guys I'm new to the Mac as coming from the Windows background. In windows I'm running my Maven Project as WildFly as it's server, so now I want the same configuration on Mac too.

> I started with setting up as below:
>
> > 1. I started by downloading JAVA from the Apple itself where it >>downloaded the latest version of JAVA 8 version 74(if I remember correctly)
> > 2. Then I tried to set the ENV variables like JAVA_HOME, PATH as described in below links:
> >
> > http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/
> >
> > [How to Set Java JDK Environment Variable for Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089697/how-to-set-java-jdk-environment-variable-for-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion)
> >
> > 3. Thereafter downloaded the Eclipse Mars
> > 4. Worked on setting up Maven by downloading Maven (latest version) but >>   it didn't work so I setup the Maven in Eclipse itself from the Eclipse >>   Marketplace.
> > 5. While working with the Maven in Eclipse it was throwing error on Eclipse and when I checked over the web about the error it was because of the wrong java version.
> > 6. Like I said in my first point I installed Java 8 from Apple store but when I tried below commands it's always gives me wrong version despite the latest JAVA

```
    Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_xx"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_xx-b02)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

    Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ javac -version
    javac 1.6.0_xx
```

> > (edited the version no. as I'm not sure now)
> >
> > 7. My next was then I downloaded the JDK 1.8 from the Oracles website and after correcting the Build Path in Eclipse, Maven began to work and now I'm able to run my Project via. Project -> Run as -> Maven build
> > 8. My next task was to run the WildFly Server so that I can deploy the war's as I used to do in windows. So I downloaded the WildFly from http://wildfly.org/downloads/ version 10.0.0.Final --> Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution (131 MB TGZ File)
> > 9. After this I made some changes in standalone.xml as per my Project needs like datasource changes. Then I tried to run but it failed with below error.

```
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ ./standalone.sh
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/prashantkumar/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../standalone/configuration/log4j.xml

=========================================================================

00:10:20,286 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
00:10:21,259 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
00:10:21,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
00:10:22,103 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131) [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299) [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected '<'  in attribute value
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [35,5]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:614) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:487) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:472) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.parseAttrValue(BasicStreamReader.java:1957) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3065) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2963) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2839) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1073) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.SystemPropertiesXml.parseSystemProperties(SystemPropertiesXml.java:71) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.CommonXml.parseSystemProperties(CommonXml.java:190) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:223) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49) [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123) [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final]
    ... 3 more

00:10:22,107 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
00:10:22,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
00:10:22,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) stopped in 8ms
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ java -version
```

> > This error is coming since start and I'm struggling for 12 straight hours without any luck.
> >
> > Please find my current settings:

```
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:bin prashantkumar$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_73
```

> > I have setup the ~.bash_profile file like below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export M2_HOME=/Users/prashantkumar/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

> > Other ENV variables

```
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:~ prashantkumar$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/prashantkumar/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:~ prashantkumar$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
```

> > Links I've tried without any luck:
>
> [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)
>   [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308)

Please guys help me out as I'm really stuck and being of Windows background I'm quiet scared to make some system file changes.

Comment: I can reproduce your `WstxParsingException` when deleting the closing `"` from the end of the last attribute in line 34 of `standalone.xml`. Maybe you accidentally deleted the double quotes when you "made some changes". Or maybe you pasted text from a text document with typographic quotes (which may be visually indistinguishable from correct double quotes)?

Comment: @halfbit Thanks a lot mate for suggesting the same, being a new to Mac I just added the Project related changes in standalone.xml file. It was Mac's double quote `”` which I used assuming this is as same as normal double quotes `"` (which should be same but not) while adding those changes. But after your suggestion I copy pasted from the existing double quotes in the standalone.xml file and it's started working like a charm. Once again thanks a lot mate & I don't know why Apple has added tilted quotes instead normal quotes in their keyboard!

Comment: what is the output of mvn --verison ? this will show what Java version Maven is using. It is also common practice to setup a ~/.m2/settings.xml file with the Maven remote and local repository settings

Comment: This is what the output which I got from mvn --version:
`Prashants-MacBook-Pro:configuration prashantkumar$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/prashantkumar/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"`