# Cordova can't build on android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, build

cordova do not want to build with android.

It compiles under ios via Xcode.

Android Studio project detected

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/arthurdoreau/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:61518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at /Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:370:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/arthurdoreau/Documents/Deeky/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:172:11)
(node:61518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:61518) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that JDK 1.8 or greater is needed. Which JDK version are you using? If you have not installed it then please install from Java website otherwise you will need to set the path of the JDK in your system paths file.

If the issue still persists, you should uninstall all previous JDK including 1.8 then install latest JDK. Although removing paths of previous JDK versions from paths variable should work too.

Comment: I use jdk-10.0.1

Comment: I did it, how do I put the JDK path in my system?

I am under macosx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089697/how-to-set-java-jdk-environment-variable-for-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion